# Mouse cursor plugin for Paint.Net

Tags: windows, gratis, graphic-design

Sometime I have screen shots where I need to add a fake mouse cursor. Therefore I'm looking for a plugin for my favorite screenshots graphics editor, Paint.NET.

That plugin should

- come with the default mouse cursors of Windows in default size
- ideally come with other configurable mouse cursors of Windows (like the high contrast ones)
- be able to use the mouse cursors as configured in the control panel (.CUR and .ANI files)

Please do not suggest that I should take screenshots including the mouse cursor. Often I don't manage to get the mouse cursor in the position I like and sometimes I use the screenshot to create several derivatives with mouse cursors in different positions.